# arm - interrupt enabling

Tags: arm, interrupt-handling, irq

I'm trying to enable interrupts and timer 2 on Allwinner A20 ([User Manual](http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/A20/A20%20User%20Manual%202013-03-22.pdf)).

cpsr reads `0x60000113`. GICD_CTRL reads `1`. GICC_CTRL reads `1`. GICD_ITARGETSR0 reads `0x01010101`. And GICD_IIDR reads `0x0100143b`.

IRQ_ENABLE_REG of the timer was enabled. STATUS_REG also changed after the timer counted down once.

But I still cannot get it running into IRQ handler. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

What I've ignored is to check the base address of exception vectors, which was written in pre-booting. IRQ behaves normally after resetting.